# Webpack watch not working on Webstorm on Windows?

Tags: webstorm, webpack, intellij-14, webpack-dev-server

So basically I have a project using Webpack, if I build using `Webpack -w`, editing the file with another editor will trigger the watch; however if I edit the file using Webstorm, nothing will happen.

I have came across this [post](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/466233;jsessionid=4E17E9ABA28D55378CDB8A43F53A8511), which seems I'm not the only one, however that solution is for Ubuntu, so I was wondering if there is anything similar for Windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Seems Webpack watch doesn't work if the file is not saved directly. Please try turning '`Safe write`' option ( `Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Use "safe write" (save changes to temporary file first)`) off.

In 2020.* the option name is `Back up files before saving`

Comment: doesn't work for me. I am using Ubuntu though. Before the watcher was watching intermittently... now after i unchecked that option, the watcher is not watching at all

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure you use Node's path construction instead of slashes. Example:

```
entry: {
     'MyPackage': path.join(__dirname, 'modules', 'PkgEntry.js'),
...
```

instead of:

```
entry: {
     'MyPackage': '\\modules\\PkgEntry.js'),
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue today. And accepted answer didn't help me.

Check this page https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit and try to increase your **Inotify Watches Limit**. Helped me.