# Webpack hot replace works only intermitently in Webstorm on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, webpack, webstorm

My webpack hot replace only works intermitently when working on devserver.

The arguments to my devserver looks like this :

```
NODE_ENV=developement ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8082 --progress --colors --hot --content-base public
```

For the longest time on this project it has been working flawlessly. Now, all of a sudden if I do a change to a file, hit **CTRL-S** for "save", it will not register the change.

I cannot see any pattern to this. Usually if I do a big change, like add 30 lines of code and save the file, then it will trigger the hot replace.

This has reduced my productivity to a crippling pace, because now I need to rebuild the whole project each time.

It was suggested I turn off saving to temp files in Webstorm **( Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Use "safe write" (save changes to temporary file first))** off in this post :

[Webpack watch not working on Webstorm on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213253/webpack-watch-not-working-on-webstorm-on-windows)

But now it is not watching at all.

**UPDATE :**

I have tried it also on Atom instead of Webstorm, so it seems not that Webstorm is the problem. I think it is more of an Ubuntu issue.

**UPDATE 2 :**

I tried to run "sudo npm run devserver" but that did not solve the problem

Comment: which editor are you using? are you sure when you press ctrl s it is saved immediately to disk , and not simply temporarily saved in memory (and later saved?)

Comment: webstorm .......

Comment: maybe have a look at this, i had the same problem once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34213253/webpack-watch-not-working-on-webstorm-on-windows

Comment: tried that, now it doesn't watch at all.